# IntelliJ Maven JAR "No main manifest attribute error"

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Trying to set up a simple project to run a simple http server.

Created Maven project, along with groupId/artifactId/version, and so on, and was able to set up so that an IDE can interpret and run the program. Currently on Java 1.8.

However, what I'm trying to accomplish is, running statements in terminal with `mvn clean package`, if I type, `"java -jar Some.jar"`, it should run the program, but it won't.

I tried creating `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` on resources folder inside `src/` or `java/`, or the root project directory, but nothing worked.

I have been changing around, trying different thing on `pom.xml`, but simply just have no luck. It's a simple setup, but I would appreciate if someone can guide me, or what steps I should take. Thanks!

Comment: Have you set up java_home env variable ?

Comment: Does https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html#Make answer your question?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Somehow that worked.. I tried something similar last night, but somehow it worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the jar built by Maven [executable](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html#Make), add the following configuration in `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        ...
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        ...
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

The key line here is `<mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>`.